# How to concatenate 2 values in StringBody in Gatling version 3.5.0

Tags: scala, gatling

I need to concatenate 2 variables in StringBody in a Gatling script. If I type only one value for example:

```
"code":"${executionRef}",
"name":"${Groups}",
```

that works. But I need to concatenate them in only one value. I have tried it in many ways but the scripts fails. Some of my attempts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```scala
"""{
  "code":"#{Groups}-$#{executionRef}"
}"""
```

Note: using the new `#{}` syntax introduced in Gatling 3.7, where old `${}` is deprecated

Comment: I am using gatling version 3.5.0

Comment: You should upgrade then, instead of sticking to old versions :)